# sealed, virtual, невиртуальные методы в C# и производительность

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, производительность, clr

Стоит задача максимального увеличения производительности в определенной части приложения. Почитав [некоторые](https://habr.com/post/165729/) статьи хабра и где-то когда-то что-то слышав или читав, принялся, кроме всего прочего, запечатывать классы и методы (а также превращать некоторые небольшие классы в структуры). 
Уже закоммитив, решил в небольшом приложении проверить, а действительно ли это дает результат.

```
class X
{
    public int NonVirtual() => DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    public virtual int Virtual() => DateTime.Now.Minute;
}

class Y : X
{
    public override int Virtual() => DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
}

class Program
{

    private static volatile int TST = 0;

    static int Slow(Y x) => x.Virtual();

    static int Fast(Y y) => y.NonVirtual();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0;
        var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch1.Start();
        var y = new Y();
        for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            TST = Fast(y);
        }
        stopwatch1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch1.Elapsed);

        stopwatch2.Start();
        for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            TST = Slow(y);
        }
        stopwatch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch2.Elapsed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Поле `TST` объявлено как `volatile`, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал вызовы.

Сначала я удивился, что разницы совсем нет, то первый цикл быстрее на пару десятков миллисекунд, то второй (хотя таблицы виртуальных методов и всё такое, логично предположить, что виртуальный метод хоть немного должен отставать).

Тогда я полез в IL:

```
IL_0001: callvirt  instance int32 PerformanceTests.X::Virtual()
```

Это вызов виртуального метода. Вроде всё нормально. Второй вызов:

```
IL_0001: callvirt  instance int32 PerformanceTests.X::NonVirtual()
```

Что, простите? `callvirt`? Разве тут не должно быть `call`? `sealed` так-же никак не влияет на вызов виртуального метода.

Хотел бы выяснить у более опытных коллег, всё-таки, есть ли смысл в запечатывании классов в плане производительности? А так-же, почему вызов невиртуальной функции в IL такой же как и виртуальной?

**Update:**
В комментариях @Grundy написал, что `callvirt` - из-за того, что метод объявлен в базовом классе. Переписал код так, что теперь используется базовый класс (т.е. `Y` - не используется). `callvirt` так и вызывается.

Comment: вы уже прошли стадию оптимизации с помощью подбора более подходящих структур данных и алгоритмов?

Comment: _Разве тут не должно быть call?_ - нет, так как метод объявлен в базовом классе

Comment: @tym32167, там всё параллельно оптимизируется, просто если касаюсь класса - делаю его `sealed`.

Comment: я к тому, что да, вызов методов класса работает медленней, чем вызов методов структур, например, но это настолько микрооптимизация, что о ней следует думать только если никаких других вариантов уже нет.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, инструкция `call` не проверяет первый аргумент (`this`) на `null`, а так как семантика C# требует такой проверки, то компилятор использует `callvirt`.

Comment: Для примера: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQYQQbwLACgEFKIwAsCAsgBQCUWehDCwAFmAM4B0V1A3PYwQB2AUwDu6Glxp98A9AgDGCALwIR4tNP4CFU3tsYKA/HpkMAvnnNA=== в трёх случаях вызов происходит с помощью `call` и в одном с `callvirt`.

Comment: @PetSerAl, прикольный ресурс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, компилятор использует `callvirt` что бы генерировать `NullReferenceException`.

Что бы получить чистую `call` инструкцию компилятор должен быть уверен, что экземпляр класса не может быть `null`. Пример:

```
class Test
{
    public void Method() => Console.WriteLine(123);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Test().Method();
}
```

`IL`-код:

```
IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApp1.Program/Test::.ctor()
IL_0006: call instance void ConsoleApp1.Program/Test::Method()
```

Если код немного изменить:

```
static Test GetTest() => new Test();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetTest().Method();
}
```

То уже получаем `callvirt`, так как компилятор предполает, что `GetTest` может вернуть `null:`

```
IL_0001: call class ConsoleApp1.Program/Test ConsoleApp1.Program::GetTest()
IL_0006: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp1.Program/Test::Method()
```

`sealed` ни на что не влияет в рантайме. Это просто маркер для разработчиков, который сообщает, что можно делать в высокоуровневом коде, а что нельзя.

Для каждого `callvirt` невиртуального метода `JIT` вставляет одну дополнительную инструкцию перед каждым `call`:

```
cmp         dword ptr [/*здесь регистр с адресом экземляра*/],ecx  
call        00007FF9CD540098  // метод
```

Эффект от одной `cmp` инструкции очень незначителен.

Comment: Про рантайм понятно. Я просто не учел, что компилятор принимает решение на основе более сложной логики, чем просто виртуальность метода.